# Make any customer domains reach a proxy with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am currently trying to create a proxy which could allow any of my customer with their own domain to reach this proxy with https.

Here what I want to achieve technically :

*customer.com/en -> proxy.saas.com/en -> saas.com/customer.com/en*

I tried many things:

**Aws**

Using api gateway with a lambda function as a proxy with custom domains,
I could allow this kind of behaviors but they are applying a quota of 120 custom domain for each instances and they do not support unbound growth.

So it did not match our need as we may need much more than 1000 customer custom domains.

**Cloudflare**

Using cloudflare for saas and though allow any customer custom hostname to reach the worker which is behaving as the proxy.

But the issue here is that to trigger the worker I need to add the custom domain to the worker.

If I only add a cname record from my customer to the worker it does trigger because of cloudflare policy.

**Conclusion**

I need to find a way to deliver content for every of my customer based on their own domains and with the ability to get certificate for https to work. And I also really need a server less / cached environnement as the load can be heavy for every of my customers.

**What can I use that I miss on cloudflare or aws ? I would love to continue on cloudflare but if their is another provider allowing my need I will choose it.**

Thanks a lot !